# Separate each value in the list Python

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have this transaction list. Each row is 1 transaction that contains the bought products. However, with the current list it understood the whole row as 1 (and doesn't recognize the products separately):

```
transaction_list
[['8HN,M7E,K09'],
 ['ANV'],
 ['UKQ,8HN,SOE,Z1G']]
```

What I really would like to do is to recognize each product of the transaction as a separate value. So the first transaction has product '8HN', 'M7E', and 'K09' like this:

```
transaction_list
[['8HN','M7E','K09'],
 ['ANV'],
 ['UKQ','8HN','SOE','Z1G']]
```

I'm actually not sure what would be the best way to approach this. I tried to use split() but it said 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.
Could anyone please give me a suggestion?

Comment: Can you share the code you used that caused the error?

Comment: This was the original code that caused error: myList = [i.split(",")[0] for i in transaction_list]

Answer (score 1):

You got an error because you were trying to split on a list instead of the string within the list: `[i.split(",")[0] for i in transaction_list]`. Here `i` is a list, and you can't apply the function split on it. So first you do `i[0]` and then split on it. Like this:

```
l =[['8HN,M7E,K09'],
 ['ANV'],
 ['UKQ,8HN,SOE,Z1G']]

[ a[0].split(",") for a in l]
```

Output:

```
[['8HN', 'M7E', 'K09'], ['ANV'], ['UKQ', '8HN', 'SOE', 'Z1G']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DavideBrex!! This works!! now I understand why my original code didn't work!

Comment: Please accept my answer if you find it helpful ([how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235))

Answer (score 0):

This is a great situation to employ a list comprehension. The code is written like so:

```
[lst[0].split(',') for lst in transaction_list]
```

In short, we are going to first comprehend each list in our transaction list and then access the first element (where the string you want to split is located) and split it into a list.  The resulting split lists then become the elements of list originally being comprehended.

If you are unfamiliar with list comprehensions: check out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

I know this answer is redundant, but it should be a bit more explanatory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed solution!

Answer (score 0):

Initially you marked this question also with *pandas* tag, so I assume that you want not plain *pythonic* list, but rather a *Series* or *DataFrame*.

The way you created your *transaction_list* is a bit unclear,
so I assumed that it was created something like:

```
transaction_list = pd.Series([['8HN,M7E,K09'], ['ANV'], ['UKQ,8HN,SOE,Z1G']])
```

so it is:

- a *Series*,
- with each element containing a **list**,
- with a **single string**.

To convert it to a DataFrame, splitting each element on a comma, you can run:

```
result = transaction_list.apply(lambda tt: pd.Series(tt[0].split(','))).fillna('')
```

getting:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  8HN  M7E  K09     
1  ANV               
2  UKQ  8HN  SOE  Z1G
```

Note that I added `.fillna('')`, otherwise non-existing element would
have been filled with *NaN*.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking to have an output in both DataFrame and list so this is great!